# Proper Way to Publish Sitefinity MediaContent

Tags: sitefinity

I want to publish Sitefinity `MediaContent` (`Document`, `Image`, and `Video` in Sitefinity Library). As i look on the documentation, they gave an example using `WorkflowManager`:

```
//Publish the DocumentLibraries item. The live version acquires new ID.
var bag = new Dictionary<string, string>();
bag.Add("ContentType", typeof(Document).FullName);
WorkflowManager.MessageWorkflow(masterDocumentId, typeof(Document), null, "Publish", false, bag);
```

Code snippet above is taken from their [documentation](https://docs.sitefinity.com/for-developers-create-documents).

The problem is, the underlying implementation of `WorkflowManager` uses `HttpContext` to check whether the current user has the required privilege. The snippet below is from decompiling the `Telerik.Sitefinity.dll`:

```
    public static string MessageWorkflow(System.Guid itemId, System.Type itemType, string providerName, string operationName, bool isCheckedOut, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string> contextBag)
    {
        ....
        dictionary.Add("operationName", operationName);
        dictionary.Add("itemId", itemId);
        dictionary.Add("providerName", providerName);
        dictionary.Add("isCheckedOut", isCheckedOut);
        dictionary.Add("contextBag", contextBag);
        dictionary.Add("culture", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name);
        dictionary.Add("httpContext", System.Web.HttpContext.Current);
        if (workflowDefinition != null)
        {
            dictionary.Add("workflowDefinitionId", workflowDefinition.Id);
        }
        contextBag.Add("userHostAddress", System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress);
        ...
    }
```

As shown above it at least calls `System.Web.HttpContext.Current` **twice** which is **bad**. Especially if i have exection deferred using `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem` or even using [Quartz](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet) that runs outside `HttpContext.Current` obviously.

My question is, is there another way to publish Sitefinity `MediaContent` in **Elevated Mode** and did not depend on **`HttpContext`** at all?

Currently i am using **Sitefinity 9.2**, as far as i am aware, the APIs above also exists on Sitefinity 7.3.

Answer (score 1):

"*As shown above it at least calls System.Web.HttpContext.Current twice which is bad*." - this is most probably an issue with the decompiler - I am sure they are not calling it twice.

For Elevated Mode you can use this, but it will still require HttpContext

```
...
SystemManager.RunWithElevatedPrivilege(p =>
{
    WorkflowManager.MessageWorkflow(id, itemType, null, "Publish", false, bag);
});
```

Comment: is this `SystemManager.RunWithElevatedPrivilege` uses the previous `HttpContext`? i just googled it a bit and found [this](https://www.sitefinity.com/developer-network/forums/sitefinity-sdk/errors-with-managers-when-multi-threading) not sure how it will behave under `QueueBackgroundWorkItem` or Quartz.. it also plagued with this [issue](https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/incomplete-invalid-uri-exception) apparently, and reflection (accessing the website url from the application itself) is not an option..

Comment: It uses SystemManager.CurrentHttpContext which I think you can try to set yourself (I've never done this though). Can't you use the Sitefinity's ScheduledTask for any background tasks?

Comment: unfortunately, no. i can't use it as the current framework already using Quartz everywhere..